# Jenkins Pipeline - inserting variable in shell creates a new line

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Choice param in my jenkins file to select environment as follows:

```
pipeline {
     agent any
     parameters {
    choice(
        name: 'ENVIRONMENT_URL',
        choices: "https://beta1.xyz.com\nhttps://beta2.xyz.com\nhttps://beta3.xyz.com",
        description: 'interesting stuff' )
  }
```

in the `Stage` section, i have the following piece

```
 stage('execute tests') {
            steps {
                script {
                        sh """URL=${ENVIRONMENT_URL} npm run e2e:tests"""
                        sh 'echo -e "\nTest Run Completed.\n"'   
                }
             }   
            }
```

However, when i run the pipeline job by selecting the choice parameter i added, the following gets executed (the inserted choice param creates a line break):

```
+ URL=https://beta1.xyz.com
+ npm run e2e:tests
```

Using the variable is causing a line break and that's what is causing issue. 
I have tried different ways to avoid line break. Tried using a variable but that didn't help. tried with different quotations, that didn't either.

What can i do to avoid line break ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `trim` method on a String class type to remove trailing whitespace and newline:

```
sh "URL=${params.ENVIRONMENT_URL.trim()} npm run e2e:tests"
```

Note I also specified your parameter is in the `params` map and removed the triple quotes as those are for multiline string formatting.

Alternatively, you can specify the choices as an array instead of as a multiline string. The `choices` argument would then appear like:

```
choice(
  name:        'ENVIRONMENT_URL',
  choices:     ['https://beta1.xyz.com', 'https://beta2.xyz.com', 'https://beta3.xyz.com'],
  description: 'interesting stuff'
)
```

Either solution would fix your issue.